# Disabling mouse acceleration not supported in Chrome v88

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pointerlock

So we use the `requestPointerLock()` function to lock the mouse pointer of users while gaming on our website. Following the [web.dev disable-mouse-acceleration article](https://web.dev/disable-mouse-acceleration/), I tested their [pointer lock API sample](https://unadjusted-movement.glitch.me/) and discovered that requesting pointer lock with "unadjustedMovement" works on my Chrome browser (v88.0.4324.104).

However, now something strange is happening. I basically just copied the above project by going to the [source code link](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/unadjusted-movement?path=script.js%3A1%3A0) and click on "remix to edit". Then, I opened the sample and did the same test, resulting in the following message:

> disabling mouse acceleration not supported

So basically, two identitcal project code where the original works flawlessly, but the copied project says disabling mouse accelaration is not supported.

Also, I've tested the exact same code in a local project, but same error message is returned.

Anyone an idea what's going wrong here?

[The original source code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/unadjusted-movement?path=script.js%3A1%3A0)
[The original live test](https://unadjusted-movement.glitch.me/)

[The source code copy](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gorgeous-cultured-prose?path=script.js%3A1%3A0)
[The live test copy](https://gorgeous-cultured-prose.glitch.me/)

Comment: It might be enabled for that site only. Try asking for help in their support forums

Comment: @Rojo Thanks! Makes sense. I'll contact them for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: It is supported by default in chromium browsers from v92

Old answer:

It is supported but only with flag

Just go to **chrome://flags/#enable-pointer-lock-options** and select enabled.
After relaunch go to https://unadjusted-movement.glitch.me/ and test it

Comment: That actually answers my question. As in it's not yet possible without manually activating the flag. Thank you!